# Drag and Drop Text and Saving to an image with jQuery and PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, image

I'm building a user generated image where they upload a picture, add flourishes and save it. I am able to get everything to work except I cannot get the X and Y axes to line up between the user placement and the image saving for the user added caption, which is a div overlay when the user enters it.

HTML and jQuery code to line up the text (user inputs via text box, jQuery replaces the value):

```
    <div id='images' style='height:480; width:640px; position:relative;'>
                <div id='caption' style='height:35; width:40px; position: absolute; bottom:50; left:310; z-index:200; padding-botom:100px; color:white; font-size:30px; text-align:center; vertical-align:bottom; border:1px solid red;'></div>
                <div id='border' style='height:480; width:640px; position: absolute; top:0; left:0; z-index:100;'><img src='' id='borderimage'></div>
                <div id='croppedimage' style='height:480; width:640px; position: absolute; top:0; left:0;'><img src='<?= $cropped ?>'></div>
        </div>

<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#caption" ).draggable({ containment: "parent", cursor:"move" });
  });
$('.thumb').click(function(){
        var bordername=$(this).attr('id') + '.png';
        $('#border').css("background-image", "url(borders/" + bordername +")");  
        $('#borderchoice').val(bordername);

});
$('#captiontext').keyup(function(){
        var cap=$('#captiontext').val();
        $('#caption').text(cap);
        var caplen=$("#captiontext").val().length;
        var capwidth=caplen * 15;
        $("#caption").width(capwidth);
});

$('#submit').click(function(){
    console.log($('#caption').position());
        var top=$('#caption').position();
        var width=$('#caption').width();
        $('#x').val(top.top);
        $('#y').val(top.left);
        $('#width').val(width);
});
</script>
```

And the PHP that handles it on the following page:

```
imagecopyresampled($dest, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $imagewidth, $imageheight, $imagewidth, $imageheight);

if (!empty($_POST['captiontext']))
{
        $color = imagecolorallocate($dest, 255, 255, 255);
        $x=$_POST['x'];
        $y=$_POST['y'];
        $fontfile='arial';
        $text=urldecode($_POST['captiontext']);
        imagettftext ( $dest, 24, 0, $x , $y , $color , $fontfile , $text );

}
```

I am aware that imagettftext xy starts at the bottom left of the first character of the text, but I cannot get a proper correlation between the two to accurately place the text. What can I do to get the correct placement of the text on the image to merge it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by modifying the JS and adding height so you are now passing Y as the bottom left of the text box.

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
    console.log($('#caption').position());
        var top=$('#caption').position();
        var width=$('#caption').width();
        var height=$('#caption').height();
        $('#x').val(top.left);
        $('#y').val(top.top + height);
        $('#width').val(width);
});
```

If that doesn't work you should try `imagettfbbox` http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php to get the bounding box of your text and then compute the location based on that

Comment: When looking at this answer, I saw that I mixed up the x and y values (in my code x was top and y was left), and fixing that as well as using your height fix corrected it all (knew the height needed to be added but it wasn't working.  Thanks.